# Suppressing print() without using sink()

Tags: r

I learn how to detect anomalies in time series and I use `detectAO` and `detectIO` functions from `TSA` package.I use them in a loop, but their output is not suppressed. As far as I know, when you use some functions in loops or functions, their output is suppressed until you use `print()` function. So I checked the source code of these functions and the author used `print()`. Is there any method to suppress this output without using `sink('/dev/null')`?

```
require(TSA)

detected<-numeric(1000)

for(i in 1:10){

  data<-rcauchy(1000)
  model<-auto.arima(data)

  #I don't want this to be printed
  detected<-detectAO(model)$ind

  #Only this
  print(detected)
}
```

Comment: Can you post some minimal reproducible code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(forecast) ## for auto.arima?                                                                                                                                                                                                          

for(i in 1:10){

  data <- rcauchy(1000)
  model <- auto.arima(data)

  ##I don't want this to be printed                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  capture.output(detected <- detectAO(model)$ind)

  ##Only this                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  print(detected)

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works flawlessly. And of course I forgot about forecast.

Comment: @SebastianOsiński feel free to mark this as the selected answer if it solved the problem